# “Independent sequences of independent random variables”?

Tags: probability-theory

I am re-reading [Takács (1959) “On a sojourn time problem in the theory of stochastic processes”](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1959-093-03/S0002-9947-1959-0109362-7/). At two points he wrote “Independent sequences of independent random variables”.

Is the second “independent” redundant, being implied by the common definition of “independent sequences”? (My [understanding](https://www.statlect.com/asymptotic-theory/sequences-of-random-variables#hid5) is that $\{X_n\}_n$ is an independent sequence of random variables if every finite subset of $\{X_n\}_n$ is a mutually independent set of random variables.)

Or is there a subtle interpretation going on here? In the statement of the main theorem the text is merely “Independent sequences of random variables” but just checking I’m not missing something?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the author is saying there are two sequences which are independent of each other, and the terms in both these sequences are independent, and that he is trying to rule out any possibility  of either of the following possible  situations:

There can be two sequences of dependent random variables, where sequence $A$ is independent of sequence $B$, but the terms in $A$ are dependent, and the terms in $B$ are dependent.  (For example $A=(X,X,X,\ldots)$ and $B=(Y,Y,\ldots)$, where $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.)

And there can be two sequences, not independent of each other, but with independent terms inside each, 
 where (say) $A=(A_1,A_2,\ldots)$ and $B=(-A_1,-A_2,\ldots)$, where the $A_n$ are independent.

At any rate, one of the instances of the puzzling "independent sequences of independent random variables" phrase, at the end of section 2 in the cited paper, refers to another [paper](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/e43ce9a534f02c5d20c7de0d67f47115/tvp4914.pdf) of the author's.  It is clear *there*  (in paragraph 2) that all the $\xi_i$ and $\eta_i$ variables in both the sequences are independent.

Comment: don't get you first line:  X,Y (in)dependent ?

Comment: I mean " ..sequences of dependent v. .. " vs. "..where X,Y are independent v. "

Comment: Now it is clear, thanks (+1)

Comment: I just supplied my [understanding](https://www.statlect.com/asymptotic-theory/sequences-of-random-variables#hid5) of how “independent sequences” are defined. I see now that the subtlety is in whether this is what the author meant.

Answer (score 0):

In a subsequent article in [1974](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1176996657), the author refers to his 1959 article as handling the case of “independent sequences” with the clear implication of “the sequences are independent of each other”. The reason is that the 1974 article introduces dependence across the sequences.